# Story about a young female red-haired, green-eyed fairy, who just graduated from her all girls school and was given the role of seamstress

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember she only lived with her mother who was also a seamstress and that you don't get to decide what you do as a job, after you graduate you're given a scroll that tells you what you do and there's only limited jobs you can get.

She found out that her mother was doing magic illegally, I don't remember if magic was fully banned or just that type of magic is banned. I think later on her mother was killed or taken, but something happened to her that caused her to go to the queen to get revenge or something.

Also the cover that I saw was the girl facing away and her hair being blown by wind and she is facing (I think) a forest and something red in the distance which I think was the kingdom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Was this a physical book or an e-book?